# Double functional dependency

Tags: database, relational-database, database-schema, database-normalization, functional-dependencies

I have a question regarding functional dependencies.
I understand that functional dependency means that the value of an attribute can be determined by the value of another attribute. 
Suppose we have this table

### |A|B|C|D|

Here A and B are the primary keys.
Is it correct to say that both C and D are functionally dependent on both A and B ?

Comment: Why do you say "A and B are the primary keys" when a table can only have one? Do you mean, candidate keys? Do you mean, the primary key is {A,B}?

Comment: You say "functional dependency means that the value of an attribute can be determined by the value of another attribute" but that is wrong because sets of attributes determine an attribute or set of attributes, plus you don't explain what "can be deterimined" means .

Answer (score 3):

You are saying “A and B are the primary keys” but this phrase is ambiguous: you mean: “*The* primary key is A B” or “the are two candidate keys, A and B”? (and note that in a relation in a relational database you can have only a single primary key and many candidate keys).

Given the definition of a (candidate) key, that is that it determines all the other attributes and that you cannot remove any attribute without losing this property, in the first case you can say that:

```
A B -> C D
```

or, which is equivalent, that:

```
A B -> C
A B -> D
```

(so C e D depends on the *combination* of A and B), while in the second case, you have that:

```
A -> C D
B -> C D
```

or, which is equivalent, that:

```
A -> C
A -> D
B -> C
B -> D
```

(that is, C and D are functionally dependent both on A and on B).

Answer (score 1):

"S **(functionally) determines** T" means that all appearances of a particular subtuple value for *attribute set* S have the same subtuple value for *attribute set* T. If we say an *attribute* X is determining or determined then it's understood that we really mean that set {X} is determining/determined.

A **superkey** is a set of attributes that determines every attribute. A CK (**candidate key**) is a superkey that contains no smaller superkey. There can be many CKs. One CK can be chosen as PK (**primary key**). (PKs play no role in relational theory.)

Since there can only be one PK, it's odd that you talk about a relation value or variable having more than one. Maybe you mean two CKs. Maybe you mean a 2-attribute PK.

It happens that if every subtuple value for a set of attributes appears just once then it is a superkey. (Each single-attribute superkey is a CK unless {} is the CK, which happens when the relation is limited to one tuple.) So it determines all attributes. But in general the dependencies tell us what the superkeys & CKs are.

So if each of A and B are CKs then each determines C and D, ie {C} and {D}. And if {A,B} is a PK then it determines C and D, ie {C} and {D}. It happens that if both T1 and T2 are determined by S then T1 U T2 is too. So either way, the CK(s) here determine(s) {C,D} also.

PS There is an ambiguity in English where it is not clear whether "both C and D are functionally dependent" means that C is dependent and D is dependent or that {C,D} is dependent. Similarly for "are functionally dependent on both A and B". So it is clearer to say "the set ..." rather than just using "both" and/or "and".